# How to use ASN.1 defined the x509 algorithmIdentifier

Tags: java, asn.1

Operating DEFINITIONS 
AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN

```
Certificate ::=SEQUENCE{
    subjectUniqueID     BIT STRING,
    operatorID          BIT STRING,
    operatetype         ENUMERATED{issue,cancel},
    time                GeneralizedTime,
    hashofcertificate   INTEGER,  
    highofblock         INTEGER,
    sigatureAlgotithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,    
    signatureValue      BIT STRING
}

AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
  algorithm       OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
  parameters      ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL
}
```

END

But eclipse compile error.The reason is "Syntax error on token "DEFINED", } expected". I don't know where is error.Can you tell me how to handle this error or how to code certificate in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use an obsolete version of X.509.  The ANY DEFINED BY is from 1988 ASN.1 which was withdrawn around 1994.  You will encounter much less headaches if you use a more current version of X.509 that defines AlgorithmIdentifier more like the following:

```
  AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
   algorithm   ALGORITHM.&id ({SupportedAlgorithms}),
   parameters  ALGORITHM.&Type ({SupportedAlgorithms}{@algorithm}) OPTIONAL}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only a guess but you could try

```
AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
  algorithm       OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
  parameters      ANY OPTIONAL
}
```

You can find example of `AlgorithmIdentifier` implemented in BouncyCastle [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/ae63147936376e85e068c7b63373d4e930c3fe58/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/AlgorithmIdentifier.java#L16)